# Specify area of operation and verify if a location falls within this region

Tags: c#, android, iphone, algorithm, geolocation

I am pretty new to mobile development, so kindly excuse this seemingly trivial question. I want to specify the area of operation for an organization and whether a location(lat, long) entered by a mobile app user (android, iphone etc.) comes under the area of operation. I need some high level ideas. One approach that comes to my mind is having a collection of areas(specified by a lat, long pair and a radius) in the database, may be sorted by different administration level, and thereafter, verifying the user's location(lat, long) against this data from the server. Is it the right approach or is there any other approach? Any guide is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your primary goal is : how can I define an area of operation?
If you go with a "circle" definition (i.e. lat, long and radius) you will end with some overlapping areas, and it can be difficult to decide the correct behaviour.
I would prefer a "squared" definition (i.e., left top corner and right bottom corner), after that you can check the coordinates coming from mobile device against data from the server, and attribute the correct area.

If you have to maintain the "circle" definition, you have to:

1. calculate the distance beetween the coordinates coming from mobile, and the center of area of operation stored in DB
2. verify that the distance is lower than the radius

The distance can be computed: dist(A,C)=\sqrt{(xA-xC)^2+(yA-yC)^2} 
where xA and yA are mobile coordinates, and xC and yC are lat and long of your area